# Homotopic maps $(X, A) \to (Y, B)$ induce homotopic maps $X/A \to X/B$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Working with a homework problem:

$X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $A\subset X$, $B\subset Y$.  I have $f,g:(X,A)\to (Y,B)$ as homotopic maps.

I need to show that the induced maps:  $\hat{f},\hat{g}$ are homotopic.

My instinct says that the homotopy I should use is $\hat{F}:I\times (X/A)\to (Y/B)$ should be given by $\hat{F}(t,[x]) := [F(t,x)]$.  I showed this map is well defined without any problem.

Edit:  More precisely, $\hat{f}$ maps the pair $(t,[x])$, where $x$ is any element in $[x]\in X/A$, to $[y]$, where $y$ is any element in $[F(t,x)]$.

But I'm having difficulty showing the map is continuous.  If I take $V$ to be an open subset of $Y/B$, how can I use the continuity of $F$ to show that $\hat{F}$ is continuous?

Comment: fixed.  I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Oh, cool. I added what I thought was enough detail but this is even better :).

Comment: where we are using that $f,g:(X,A)\to (Y,B)$ are homotopic in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104795/homotopic-maps-x-a-to-y-b-induce-homotopic-maps-x-a-to-x-b.

Answer (score 4):

Here's something you could use: the topology on $X/A$ comes from the [quotient map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space) $q\colon X \to X/A$. We know how to define continuous maps out of quotient spaces, and so it would be helpful if $\operatorname{id} \times q\colon I \times X \to I \times X/A$ were a quotient map. And indeed it is, because $I$ is [locally compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space): this is a theorem, the proof of which is surprisingly long, of Whitehead's. See Lemma 2.88 [here](http://www.math.ku.dk/~moller/e03/3gt/notes/gtnotes.pdf).

Comment: It's good to know that in general the product of two quotient maps need not be a quotient map. I've graded enough algebraic topology papers to know that this is an attractive fallacy. Anyway, hopefully there is an easier way of showing your result, but this is a nice result to have in your toolbelt, I think.

Comment: Your remark is actually a hint at the beginning of my assignment.  :)

Comment: Could you help me with this please? where we are using that $f,g:(X,A)\to (Y,B)$ are homotopic in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104795/homotopic-maps-x-a-to-y-b-induce-homotopic-maps-x-a-to-x-b.