# Truncated alternating sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

Are there any nice counting arguments that identify the sum

$$S_{n,k} = {n \choose k} - {n \choose k-1} + {n \choose k-2} + \cdots + (-1)^k {n \choose 0}$$

with a simpler, more conceptually-appealing expression?

This expression comes up as the type of rank of a homology group of a somewhat complicated object and I'm hopeful I might be inspired by a counting argument.

Comment: $S_{n,0}=1$ doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks.  I did not think about those properties as carefully as I should have.  I'll just edit them out.

Comment: @RyanBudney Could you help me with this please? where we are using that $f,g:(X,A)\to (Y,B)$ are homotopic in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104795/homotopic-maps-x-a-to-y-b-induce-homotopic-maps-x-a-to-x-b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S_{n,k}=\binom{n-1}k.$$
Look at the subsets of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ of size $\le k$, and pair
off $A$ with $A\cup\{n\}$ for $A\subseteq[n-1]$. The unpaired sets are
the $k$-element subsets of $[n-1]$.

Comment: It seems to be the binomial expansion of $(1-1)^n$.

Comment: @sirous No, since it only goes part of the way.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.